# Is there an Amazon Route 53 analog in Azure?

Tags: azure

I am really new to Azure (I have participated in only one project that used this cloud), perhaps you could provide a sample of "route 53 analog" usage in Azure?

Answer (score 4):

Check out `Azure DNS Service` - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/dns/. It is currently in preview.